# Visualise timeseries in kibana without aggregate metrics

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

## Use case

I generated some test json documents that I am sending into an index called `test` in `elasticsearch` in the following format:

```
{
"name": "MyTestModel",
"@timestamp": 1516790713,
"performance": {
  "precision": 75.5,
  "recall": 78.7,
  "f1-score": 77.1,
  "accuracy": 95.4
}
```

I can see them when searching, and know they are indexed properly.

I would like to use `timelion` or `visualize` in `kibana` to be able to view a series of these documents as a line chart.

But in `timelion` I have tried many queries, but they don't seem to work.

```
.elasticsearch(timefield="@timestamp", index=test, q="MyTestModel")
```

I don't believe using aggregate metrics makes sense (`count`,`min`,`avg`, `etc.`) since they are values that are already computed a priori, so I am excluding them from `.elasticsearch()` .

## Question

How can you visualize the timeseries data in these json documents as a line graph in kibana (`timelion` or `visualize`)?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to see in Timelion. A line, ok, but this only uses the time series, what do you want that line to represent? A count of documents on that timerange? If you don't want to use count, avg, sum etc then there is nothing else to see.

Comment: I want to have a series of these json documents each representing a single data point which can be precision, recall, f1 or accuracy. Therefore the json documents do not need to be counted or averaged, they just need to display each data point for each time t

Comment: Depending on how many points there are and how frequent (every second?) ES has to aggregate those values in a certain bucket of time. Question for you: what if on the same second you have multiple documents with different values for `precision`? What would you want to see on the graph?

Comment: So you want to chart the documents themselves because they already contain aggregated information. It looks like your timestamp has second-level precision, do you happen to have many documents the same second? If not, simply choose "second" precision in your date histogram and pick the `avg` metric and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @andrei, we can use milliseconds, that is fine. I dont ever expect any model `name` to ever add results at the same millisecond. @val There is the issue that an aggregate will average any model `name` around a millisecond.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this easily. Kibana and Timelion use date range aggregations and for seconds or milliseconds there can potentially be lots of those buckets. And those require memory. If you want to do this in Kibana or Timelion you need to use one of those metrics.

Comment: Sadly this is what I thought (and did not want to hear)

Comment: @Nathan do you have more than one document per millisecond? Otherwise, it's really easy to couple the JS ES client with a [timeseries charting lib](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html) and chart what you need. Few lines of code and you're running...

Comment: Yes, i will have to develop another solution. thanks @val

Comment: so you have more than one doc per millisecond, ok

Comment: In reality, any given model will not have more than one data point per millisecond, but multiple models could. Therefore aggregates can be problematic if you want to plot multiple model metrics on the same graph.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kibana or those other tools, but I am very familiar with time series charting and aggregates. Typically time series charting solutions do use aggregates, because typically users want to support time scales other than the finest resolution (millisecond in your case). Do you really not ever need to chart scales larger than one millisecond? Also, a good charting solution should *not* aggregate when using the finest resolution, even if an aggregate is supplied. Are you *sure* that kibana/etc. actually use the aggregate when displaying millisecond resolution? (Did you test?)

Comment: Also, sometimes just thinking about what the right aggregate for your data *would* be (if any) is a helpful exercise. For most common numeric data types I've seen, *some* aggregator makes sense. Usually average or count/sum.